# Filter content for each item in list coming from AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view which has the following code

```
<div class="filter-recipe-wrapper">
<form method="post" action="/Recipe/SearchFilterResult" id="filterRecipes">
    <input type="checkbox" name="difficulty" value="Easy"> Easy<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="difficulty" value="Medium"> Medium<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="difficulty" value="Hard"> Hard<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

on submitting this form I have a Ajax function which does the following:

```
var filteredItems = [];
var url = $(this).attr('action');
$("input:checkbox[name=difficulty]:checked").each(function(){
    filteredItems.push($(this).val());
});
var dataString = 'SearchTerm=' + filteredItems;
alert(filteredItems);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: dataString,
    success: function(response) {  
       alert(response);
    },
        error: function() {}
});
```

my controller action code is :

```
public ActionResult SearchFilterResult(IEnumerable<string> searchTerm = null)
    {

        return Content("ok");


    }
```

The problem is 1. The string which is received here gets returned as only 1 item instead of 3 when all three checkboxes are selected.

Once problem 1 is solved, I want to be able to query my database and display all recipes which have those matches for difficulty.

Comment: It would need to be `data: { searchTerm: filteredItems },`

Comment: However, you will find this far easier if you bind to 3 properties, `bool IsEasy`, `bool IsMedium` and `bool isHard` and serialize you form and post it.

Comment: Can you post an example of the searchTerm and how it would be pulled int the MVC Action please ? Also, I am not using bool because right now for testing purpose there are just 3 checkboxes but there will be many of them later when three are working fine at first.

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped it in an event handler but perhaps you can use this to resolve your issue:

```
function mysubmit(e) {
    var filteredItems = [];
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    $("input[type=checkbox][name=difficulty]:checked").each(function () {
        filteredItems.push($(this).val());
    });
    // var dataString = 'SearchTerm=' + filteredItems;
    var dataString = {
        searchTerm: filteredItems
    };
    alert(dataString.searchTerm);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: dataString,
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function () {}
    });
}
$('#filterRecipes').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    mysubmit(e);
});
```

Comment: I will try this and mark it correct if it works with my solution. Thanks for the help. However on the controller code for this function, should I continue using a IEnumerable<string> to store these values ?

Comment: It almost seems as if you might have a new question here and for that I would consider a List of check box with a model something like: `public class CheckBoxModel   
    {  
        public int Id   
        {  
            get;  
            set;  
        }  
        public string Name   
        {  
            get;  
            set;  
        }  
        public bool Checked   
        {  
            get;  
            set;  
        }  
    }  
} `

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing an array to your controller pass string

convert your array to string using `JSON.stringify(filteredItems)`

Also for your

```
$("input[type=checkbox][name=difficulty]:checked").each(function () {
    filteredItems.push($(this).val());
});
```

use [jQuery Map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

```
$("input[type=checkbox][name=difficulty]:checked").map(function(){
  return $.trim($(this).val());
})
```

When you receive this as parameter in your controller try to deserialize to your class

```
(new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<T>(str);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not sure how you are saving the return $.trim part and how you are using Deserialize. Can you elaborate please ?

Comment: trimming will help you to remove any whitespace padding. jQuery map will return you an array from the array.

and about Deserialize you are using default .NET library.

For your references

1) https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/
2) http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/
3) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx